# How does Twitter.com logout users after cache clear?

Tags: security, authentication, cookies, twitter

I noticed something very interesting this afternoon - when I clear my browser cache and cookies, Twitter immediately signs me out.

I assume they are polling for an authentication cookie every second or so via Javascript, and signing out users if the cookie is missing. Any other guesses as to how this is done?

Since this is my first encounter with this behavior, I'm wondering how common it is, the best way to accomplish it, and any security concerns one should have when implementing it (if any).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The only way any site knows that you are logged in is via a cookie that your browser sends on subsequent requests.  If the cookie no longer exists then by definition you are no longer logged into their site.

I'm not exactly sure what you are asking regarding the "best way to accomplish it"..  Best way to accomplish what exactly?

If your asking what the best way is to accomplish keeping a browser logged in via a cookie, then it boils down to storing  a session or user id in the cookie.  Session ID is much preferred as it is a different value for each "session".

Regarding how common using cookies for security is: they are pretty much everywhere.  The only time cookies aren't used for storing your session id is if the session id appears in the query string.

Now onto security concerns.  Usually those cookies have a very limited lifespan, that to your browser session so that when you close the browser the cookie expires.  If the site is ssl enabled then the contents of the cookie are encrypted as they pass over the wire.  If not, well, you don't have any defense against man in the middle or packet capture attacks. (look up firesheep).

Comment: I guess my question then becomes what's the best way to check for the auth cookie? Is there a recommended practice, interval to monitor it, etc... This is a pretty rare behavior as far as I can tell. Most site's don't monitor the cookie actively on the client side and are only concerned with whether new requests are authenticated or not.

Comment: @Derek Hunziker: They aren't monitoring the cookie.  Twitter sends requests via ajax back to their servers.  Each request, by definition, passes the cookie.  In the event the cookie doesn't exist you have to log in again.  Nothing magical here.

Comment: @Jeff Ferland: You are correct, not sure what I was thinking. Updated answer.

Answer (score 3):

While you have twitter open, some javascript code polls the server periodically for new tweets. What happened was you cleared your cache very close to polling time, so it appeared that your cache clearing logged you out, when in reality it was just a scheduled poll.  Since you cleared your cookies, when twitter went to check for more tweets, that request didn't have your login cookie and the server logged you out.

I just tested this, and when I clear my cookies, nothing happens for a bit until twitter tries to get more tweets.